# Duplicate title tags and meta descriptions after removing .html extension from files

Tags: seo, google-search-console, htaccess, duplicate-content

Google Webmaster Tools/Search Console is giving me errors regarding duplicate title tags and meta descriptions.

The website in question is a static HTML website. All documents do have a `.html` extension. In order to remove the `.html` from all documents I am using the code below in my *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

So for example `http://example.com/about.html` becomes `http://example.com/about` Now Google thinks that there are two separate about pages -
 even though it's only one. Can someone explain to me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `.html` URLs were already indexed at the time you changed your URLs (and removed the `.html` extension) then the only way to preserve your SEO and avoid duplicate content from the get go is to implement 301 redirects from the `.html` URL to your desired URL.

(This assumes you have changed all the URLs in your application to your desired "extensionless" URLs.)

Something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The check against `REDIRECT_STATUS` is to avoid a redirect loop by ensuring the rewritten request (to `.html`) is not redirected (when the internal rewrite is triggered, `REDIRECT_STATUS` is set to `200`).

---

> In order to remove the `.html` from all documents I am using the code below in my *.htaccess* file

*Aside:* I guess this is probably just how you are describing it, but that isn't actually what that snippet of code does. You "remove the `.html`" from the URL by physically changing the URLs in your application (not with `.htaccess`). You then use `.htaccess` to *internally rewrite* the URL back to the actual filesystem path (with the `.html` extension) - and it's this that your snippet of code does. It re-appends the `.html` extension, it doesn't remove it.

Comment: The website is very new and preserving any SEO doesn't play a role at this point. Does this mean that a 301 redirect is still the preferred solution? (Including the canonical links without the .html extension.)

Comment: Yes, a 301 redirect would be the preferred solution in order to eliminate the duplicate content warnings. However, a canonical tag should have been enough if the URLs were not already indexed and all the internal links are correct. If the "website is very new" and the `.html` URLs were not already indexed but still you are getting a duplicate content warning in GSC then it suggests a problem with your link structure (sitemap, etc.) - otherwise, Google should not have discovered the `.html` links in the first place.

Comment: Indeed the outdated sitemap.xml file could be the problem! All the links in there do have .html extensions... so Google most likely have indexed it. I have updated the sitemap. Let's see if it changes something

Answer (score 4):

Let's assign www.example.com/about - Is your main URL and that URL you want to index in Google.

And www.example.com/about.html - Is your duplicate URL and that you don't want to index it on Google.

So There are two perfect solution. You can use any one or both.

1 ) [Use 301 redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) from example.com/about.html to example.com/about 
. So Google will index only the final or redirected version of URL.

2) [Use Canonical link tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) on head section.

Your pages are duplicate hence your canonical link tag will be same on all these pages.

```
www.example.com/about/
www.example.com/about
www.example.com/about.html
www.example.com/about/index.html
```

So when you place below canonical link tag then all above pages will inheirt same canonical link tag, just like the webpage title/description is same for all URL's

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/about" />
```

So here Google will index only that canonical link tag, other pages will consider as duplicate and Google avoid to index it.

Comment: All pages actually do have correct canonical link tags already. For example:

http://example.com/about.html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/about" />

Remember, I am removing the .HTML extension in the .htaccess file

Comment: Both pages are accessible via browser, right? Both display same result but there is no any redirection, so do 301 redirection And I think your canonical link tag is not same for duplicate pages, Is `example.com/about` and `example.com/about.html` contain same canonical link tag?

Comment: @Alex This answer is correct. You are doing a rewrite so that any search engine thinks the about.html is resolvable because the rewrite is transparent and a 202 result code is given. Your canonical tag gives a clue that /about exists which also resolves with a 202. However, with a redirect, the about.html is replaced with /about and you get what you want.

Comment: @Goyllo Both pages are accessible in the browser and display the exact same result because it's actually one an the same page. There are not two versions because example.com/about is the same as example.com/about.html and there is no redirection. This also means that I am only having one canonical link in this page which is <link rel="canonical" href="example.com/about"; />

Comment: @Goyllo If I understand your comments and answers correctly, I need to add 301 redirects  to all individual pages and duplicate content is not an issue regarding SEO?

Comment: Both solution works 1) Here [Stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106303/) doing 301 redirection, so as I said Google will follow 301 redirection just like our browser do and will index the final URL  2) Here [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/300416/) does not redirect but there is proper canonical link tag, hence Google will index only the canonical version of URL. Both solution works. Use any which is easiest for you. I prefer 301 redirection.